# rufus showed me truncated iso error

Tags: error-handling

I downloaded the latest ubuntu from the site and also the rufus. When I choose the iso file, rufus showed me truncated iso error. Plz help
It told me to re download the file.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO after download? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) to ensure it was perfect before writing to installation media?   Please also try and be precise with details.. as we can't know if you meant *latest* release,  *latest* LTS (ie. 4 releases ago), or something different (*latest* daily - in which case which one?) nor architecture, nor product (Core? Server? Desktop?) you're asking about etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually whenever I downloaded the iso and moved it into another place, its size would decrease. I instead copied the iso and found the iso perfect. I DISCOVERED THAT MOVING AN ISO IS NOT THE PROPER WAY.

Comment: Moving a file should never change its physical size. If it does you have a problem.

Comment: Exactly ^^^ Do yourself a favor and DON'T make it worse by using obsolete and unsupported OSes - https://superuser.com/questions/1702775/windows-7-install-not-starting-hardware-or-software-change-could-be-cause - . You'll make yourself a perfect victim and for no good rational reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Plz help It told me to re download the file.

And that is exactly what you should do, because if Rufus tells you that the size of your ISO is smaller than the size it is declared to occupy, then your download **IS** corrupted and you need to download the ISO again.

You can also validate this by checking the SHA-256, which Rufus can do:

1. Open your Ubuntu ISO in Rufus.
2. Click the `(✓)` button next to the `SELECT` button.
3. Visit https://releases.ubuntu.com/21.10/SHA256SUMS or https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.3/SHA256SUMS depending on whether you are using the latest Desktop or LTS.
4. Check the SHA-256 field in Rufus. It should have the same value as the one you can find in the `SHA256SUMS` file from the web (for instance, if you downloaded `ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64.iso` it should be `f8d3ab0faeaecb5d26628ae1aa21c9a13e0a242c381aa08157db8624d574b830`).
5. If the value you get from Rufus is not the same as the one from `SHA256SUMS` then your download **IS** corrupted and you will need to download the ISO again until the values match. There is **NO** other alternative but to download the ISO again (and possibly fix your network connection or a failing hard drive on your computer, if you consistently happen to download ISOs that are corrupted).

Comment: Thanks. I got to know that copying an iso is very safe compared to moving it since iso files are sensitive.